# please assist with this regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for only the text that is in the parenthesis, INCLUDING the parenthesis in the following sentence: ""Here is a house. The house is blue. (12.6)"". So I want to select --> (12.6) <--

Comment: What regex do you have so far?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? This is quite basic regex. And what is the language or tool that you are using?

Comment: you should specify the language/tool you are using..regex implementation differ's across languages/tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
\(\d+\.\d+\)
```

This is assuming you'll have only digits in that sub-string, and always in the form: (xy.zd)

Since I have no clue what language, tool, pattern, wtv you're using, I'm just leaving the basic regex.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this regex returns an array of the text items surrounded with brackets:

```
 "Here is a house. The house is blue. (12.6) (3)".match(/\([^\)]*\)/g);
```

Returns:

```
["(12.6)", "(3)"]
```

Cheers.

Comment: This is going to break horribly when you have 2 or more instances of number in parentheses.

Comment: He said "I am trying to write a regex for only the text that is in the parenthesis"... what are you talking about? (I'm confused!!!)

Comment: Test your regex on the string `"something (3) more (4)"`